# Ambient Light Sensor to monitor light levels in buildings for warranty post LED upgrade

Tags: sensors, lighting, monitoring

We are a lighting service contractor that installs and maintains lighting systems and controls. I would like to be able to offer a system that can monitor light levels using a proprietary web portal as a valuable addition to our lighting system upgrades. When our customers purchase “Lighting as a Service” (LaaS) we could then offer guaranteed light levels over time and have a tool to verify. Please let me know if you know of a system that can accomplish this.

Measurement of light levels post installation of the new LED lighting system. The measurement post installation from day one is the delta. We want to measure the depreciation of the ambient light over time.

LED lighting performance and depreciation is tested and warranted based on tests LM79, LM80 that project the useful life of the system. Most systems useful life is considered ended when the system's light output depreciates by 30% (L70).

Manufacturers offer warranties on their LED lighting products based on these tests and project the useful life based on burn hours or calculated years of service. By installing a measurement tool during the installation of a new LED lighting system, that will measure the light levels real time from the first day of installation and over the projected life of the system we could verify the light levels are within the L70 requirement.

Comment: are you asking for a verification of the system's existence?

Comment: There are plenty of light sensors using plenty of different technologies. I fear the difficulty is to define what is correct light levels. If you have windows which let in natural light, you’ll be measuring that, not the light of the LEDs. Alternatively, if you measure it when the lights are off... and if you have dimming... you thus need to couple measurements with the on/off status and possibly dimming level to get something meaningful.

Comment: Hi! It is not clear to me if you want something ready to go, just checking for competitors or if you are evaluating the possibility of developing your own products.

Comment: I would have thought getting calibrated readers would be simple - Google shows up plenty with NIST traceability.  My concern is if the warranty allows for measurement in place or if you have to have a closed chamber to mange both ambient and reflected light.  This can change your requirements drastically...